# Making bar graphs for binary outcomes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I want to make a graph with two bars displaying yes vs no outcomes grouped by age bin categories (0-20), (20-40), etc. with the count shown on the left

I tried to use this code:

```
breaks <- c(0, 20, 40, 60, 100)


# Create age groups using the cut() function
data0$age_group <- cut(data0$Age, breaks = breaks, labels = c("0-20", "20-40", "40-60", "60-100"))

# Create a bar graph
ggplot(data0, aes(x = age_group, fill = factor(cancer.at.7.years))) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(x = "Age Bins", y = "Count", title = "Bar Graph with Binary Outcome") +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("No", "Yes")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

however the age categories do not display and a bar for "No" only results

Comment: It's not possible to help you here without knowing the exact structure of your data. You can [edit] your question to include the output from `dput(data0)`. The problem should be easy to fix if you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Without your data it is difficult to help. However, here is both your original plot and a suggested where the counts are separated. Adjust labels as desired.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data0 = data.frame(
  Age = runif(n = 100, min = 0, max = 100),
  cancer.at.7.years = sample(x = c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
)

breaks <- c(0, 20, 40, 60, 100)

# Create age groups using the cut() function
data0$age_group <- cut(data0$Age, breaks = breaks, labels = c("0-20", "20-40", "40-60", "60-100"))

# Create a bar graph
ggplot(data0, aes(x = age_group, fill = factor(cancer.at.7.years))) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(x = "Age Bins", y = "Count", title = "Bar Graph with Binary Outcome") +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("No", "Yes")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
# Alternatively for better separation
ggplot(data0, aes(x = age_group, fill = factor(cancer.at.7.years))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Age Bins", y = "Count", title = "Bar Graph with Binary Outcome") +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("No", "Yes")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>